# Change effect of Back and Forward button on mouse

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse, mouse-click, wireless-mouse

I have a mouse and it has two buttons : **Back** and **Forward** .

Is there any method to change the function of this two buttons ?

For example, i want to change them into : **PageUp** and **PageDown**.

Comment: What is the brand and model number of the mouse?

Comment: @Sickest i have found the Solution. check the answer ;)

Comment: Well, didn't answer my question, what is the model number of the mouse?

Comment: @Sickest this is Uctech BL6600

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found this nice program : [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/changing-and-customizing-your-mouse-buttons-actions/)

It is a third party mouse macro program that allows custom button settings on any mouse to assign new functionality to any button.

Comment: In this situation, the mouse is a generic mouse, it has no software. Normally, an "advanced mouse" that's made by a large company will include software, in which you can adjust the settings that you have. This basically generic mouse didn't, so you needed to find stand alone software to do the trick.